# Any ideas on how to merge different excel's sheets into 1 Google spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I gotta do this task: to merge data from different excel's spreadsheets in different computers into a single Google spreadsheet (or a spreadsheet in some kind of virtual cloud).

I've been lurking around but I didn't see anything.

Comment: Is a simple copy&paste not an option for you? Can you provide some more information regarding how you want the excel sheets to be merged? Are you looking for a macro to do the merging for you?

Comment: @CATSandCATSandCATS copy&paste is not an option. The excel files' data will have to be pasted into this common google spreadsheets with a macro.

Comment: Do you have an example of the code you started? And which errors it was throwing?

Comment: @CATSandCATSandCATS I answered below

Answer (score 0):

copy/paste all your Excel files here: **https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create**

also you can upload all files to Drive - **https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive** and then convert them to Google sheets or install this and sync it to the Drive - **https://www.google.com/drive/download/**